# in Laravel filament, how I can add the relation manager to the create page?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

I have added this command

```
 php artisan help make:filament-relation-manager ProductResource tags name
```

and added in `ProductResource`

```
public static function getRelations(): array
    {
        return [
            TagsRelationManager::class
        ];
    }
```

the relation manager is shown successfully in the edit product page, but not shown in the create page. How I can display it in the create page as well?

Comment: I don't think it's not possible, in your use-case why you want to show in create page?
That relationship will not know where to add/update those relations if you provide in create

Comment: after create your record automatically apeares the relation manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relation Manager actually works with existing records.

##### Why It's working with the Edit record

- It's working on the Edit page because the record exists and then using that record you can attach/detach and add new records using the relationships

##### Why it will not work with the create record

- It will not work on the Create page because the record is not created, so it will not be clear for which record it will attach/detach or sync with.

Hope it will clear your doubt